# Type class instance not being used when deriving containing data structure

Tags: haskell, typeclass, deriving

I've been exploring using more `newtype` wrappers in my code to make more distinct types. I also do a lot of cheap serialization using Read/Show, particularly as a simple form of strongly-typed config file. I ran into this today:

The example starts like this, and I define a simple newtype to wrap around Int, along with a named field for unwrapping:

```
module Main where

import Debug.Trace ( trace )
import Text.Read ( readEither )


newtype Bar = Bar { unBar :: Int }
   deriving Show
```

Custom instance to read one of these from a simple Int syntax. The idea here is it would be great to be able to put "42" into a config file instead of "Bar { unBar = 42 }"

This instance also has trace "logging" so we can see when this instance is really used when observing the problem.

```
instance Read Bar where
   readsPrec _ s = [(Bar i, "")]
      where i = read (trace ("[debug \"" ++ s ++ "\"]") s)
```

Now another type containing a Bar. This one will just auto-derive Read.

```
data Foo = Foo { bar :: Bar }
   deriving (Read, Show)


main :: IO ()
main = do
```

Deserializing the Bar type alone works fine and uses the Read instance above

```
   print $ ((readEither "42") :: Either String Bar)
   putStrLn ""
```

But for some reason Foo, containing a Bar, and automatically derived into Read, is not drilling down and picking up Bar's instances!
(Notice that the debug message from trace isn't displayed either)

```
   print $ ((readEither "Foo { bar = 42 }") :: Either String Foo)
   putStrLn ""
```

So ok, how about the default Show form for Bar, should match the default Read right?

```
   print $ ((readEither "Foo { bar = Bar { unBar = 42 } }") :: Either String Foo)
```

No! Doesn't work either!! Again, no debug message.

Here's the execution output:

```
  $ stack exec readbug
  [debug "42"]
  Right (Bar {unBar = 42})

  Left "Prelude.read: no parse"

  Left "Prelude.read: no parse"
```

This looks buggy to me but I'd love to hear that I'm doing it wrong.

A fully working example of the code above is available. See the file `src/Main.lhs` in a [test project on darcshub](http://hub.darcs.net/dino/wrk-newtype-read)

Comment: This is a very nice question. I love just how easy you've made it for someone to start debugging your code. Hopefully my answer is helpful in identifying the particular problem you are having. That aside, I would _not_ recommend ever using `Read` for anything more than debugging - and then make sure that `read . show = id`. I would put my config in either a JSON (and use `aeson` to encode/decode), or (if you insist on a custom parser) use something like `attoparsec` or `megaparsec`. `Read` is a phenomenally inefficient parser, because it is willing to backtrack anywhere.

Comment: You're wrong: the derived instance for `Foo` *is* using the `Read` instance for `Bar` that you wrote! It's just that the `Foo` instance is failing before it bothers to force the value of `Bar` (hence never forces the thunk with the `trace` in it), because `Bar` incorrectly reports that it consumed all the remaining input and so the `Foo` reader doesn't see the `}` it needs to succeed.

Comment: @Alec I hadn't considered using JSON for configs. Keeps the typing and hierarchical structure. And then you end up with a config file that's usable by other languages/systems. I'll explore this with newtypes a bit now. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in `Read`. `readsPrec` needs to consider the possibility that it might see some more stuff after the `Bar`. [Quoting the Prelude](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:readsPrec):

> `readsPrec d s` attempts to parse a value from the front of the string, returning a list of `(<parsed value>, <remaining string>)` pairs. If there is no successful parse, the returned list is empty.

In your case, you want:

```
instance Read Bar where
   readsPrec d s = [ (Bar i, s') | (i, s') <- readsPrec d tracedS ]
      where tracedS = trace ("[debug \"" ++ s ++ "\"]") s
```

Then, the following works:

```
ghci> print $ ((readEither "Foo { bar = 42 }") :: Either String Foo)
[debug " 42 }"]
Right (Foo {bar = Bar {unBar = 42}})
```

Your other problem, namely:

> So ok, how about the default Show form for Bar, should match the default Read right?
>
> ```
>  print $ ((readEither "Foo { bar = Bar { unBar = 42 } }") :: Either String Foo)
> ```

is your fault: you defined a `Read` instance for `Bar` such that `read . show` isn't an identity operation. When `Foo` derives `Read`, it uses `Bar`s `Read` instance (it doesn't try to regenerate the code that `Bar` would've generated if you had derived `Read` on it).

Comment: I know it's kind of a tangent, but I can't help suggesting it: `instance Read Bar where readsPrec = coerce (readsPrec @Int)`

Comment: @Alec Ah! I didn't realize this difference between `read` and `readsPrec` but it makes a lot more sense to use the same function. Thank you.

Comment: @DanielWagner Ooh, I do like the terseness of that. I didn't know about Data.Coerce. I wonder if it's more efficient. Also requires `-XTypeApplications`  Thanks!

Comment: @dino `coerce` can sometimes make a big efficiency difference -- but in this case it will almost certainly be unnoticeable.